# Python: Replacing words in a sentence given user input

Tags: python

[Image of question and example inputs and outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbhCg.jpg)

The user gives two inputs, words to be replaced and the word that replaces it, and then a sentence that requires words to be replaced.

```
words = input()
word_pairs = words.split('   ')
replacement_words = {}

#put word pairs into dictionary
for pair in word_pairs:
    split_pair = pair.split(' ')
    replacement_words[split_pair[0]] = split_pair[1]

#next input and replacing words
sentence = input()

for key, value in replacement_words.items():
    new_sentence = sentence.replace(str(key), str(value))

print(new_sentence)
```

Input: automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids
(there are three spaces between each pair)

The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.

Output: The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for kids if the automobile doesn't already have one.

I am not sure why it is only replacing children for kids and not replacing the other words as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in your code, the sentence was getting replaced on every iteration. The following code solves that problem:

```
words = input("")
word_pairs = words.split('   ')

#next input and replacing words
sentence = input()

#put word pairs into dictionary
for pair in word_pairs:
    split_pair = pair.split(' ')
    sentence = sentence.replace(split_pair[0],split_pair[1])

print(sentence)
```

**Note:** In your code, the `words` variable is used only once. So, you can directly just split the input without having to create a variable. Also, from a user's perspective, it makes more sense to put the sentence first and then the words which need to be removed. Code implementing these changes:

```
#next input and replacing words
sentence = input()

word_pairs = input("").split('   ')

#put word pairs into dictionary
for pair in word_pairs:
    split_pair = pair.split(' ')
    sentence = sentence.replace(split_pair[0],split_pair[1])

print(sentence)
```

Comment: While I agree that having the user enter the sentence first makes more sense from a human perspective, the ordering of the inputs is most likely set by the specification used by whatever auto-grading system the original poster is trying to pass.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety The order of the inputs isn't much of a problem really. I just wanted to let the OP know that the mentioned order would be better. Also, I didn't know that the OP is trying to attempt some grading system

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I was looking for. I should have included that I was trying to pass an auto-grading system. Your post was very detailed and helped me grasp the concepts a little better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that in the for loop where you replace the words, you are assigning the replaced sentence to the variable new_sentence. This means that each time you run the loop, you are only storing the sentence with the most recent replacements, discarding the sentences with the previous replacements.

To fix this, you can use a different approach to replace the words in the sentence. Instead of using a loop, you can directly pass the replacement_words dictionary to the str.translate() method along with a translation table.

```
words = input()
word_pairs = words.split('   ')
replacement_words = {}

#put word pairs into dictionary
for pair in word_pairs:
    split_pair = pair.split(' ')
    replacement_words[split_pair[0]] = split_pair[1]

# create translation table
translation_table = str.maketrans(replacement_words)

#next input and replacing words
sentence = input()

# replace words using translation table
new_sentence = sentence.translate(translation_table)

print(new_sentence)
```

Also in your code you will change the sub-words, so it's better to use this function:

```
def replace_words(sentence, replacement_words):
    # split sentence into words
    words = sentence.split(' ')

    # replace words using the replacement_words dictionary
    new_words = [replacement_words.get(word, word) for word in words]

    # join words back into a sentence
    new_sentence = ' '.join(new_words)

    return new_sentence

new_sentence = replace_words(sentence, replacement_words)
```